# How do I add a tooltip to the x-axis labels in highcharts?

Tags: jquery, highcharts, tooltip, label, axis-labels

How do I add a tooltip to the x-axis labels in highcharts?

```
xAxis: {
  categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'],
  labels: {
    x: 5,
    useHTML: true,
    formatter: function () {
      return categoryImgs[this.value];
    }
  }
}
```

Currently, tooltips are only shown on the points in the chart, I want the user to also see a tooltip/custom description when hovering on the labels on x-axis. Is that possible? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general Highcharts doesn't support tooltip on labels.

However you have two solutions:

- use `Custom-events` plugin, to add event on labels: https://www.highcharts.com/products/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events (demo has click, mouse over should work the same to display custom tooltip)
- use some plugin (Tooltipsy etc.), like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gW4p6/196/

Comment: It works, just tooltipsy in the demo is loaded from github and github some time ago disabled loading js directly from a repo. See demo with loaded tooltipsy in a script tag: http://jsfiddle.net/gW4p6/272/

Comment: @PawełFus  somedirection means that the first plugin- Custom-events is no longer available on the website.

Comment: I would suggest not using anything made from Black Label, as most anything is unsupported these days, and it is very clunky (if it works at all) with `Highcharts v6` and above. Especially if you are using `@typings`.

Comment: Hi @SovietFrontier, Thanks for the message. The whole Highcharts and also some of Black Label plugins are in the middle of migration process, so they can fully support TypeScript. If you have any obstacles or comments using Plugins or Core Highcharts, it would be great if you could provide us with this information so we can improve and prepare the product that will more and more suit our customers needs.

Answer (score 2):

you can use formatter to make the label as a div. you can write your own jquery museOver event to it.

```
formatter: function(){
    return "<div class='myClass'> " + this.value + "</div>"
}
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks strikers, this will work too, but the plugin from Pawel seems to give a lot of useful features, too!

Comment: this is a pretty powerful answer

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a simpler solution to this question that just involves Bootstrap and JQuery.

See http://jsfiddle.net/key2xanadu/zfsfz0c9/.

The solution involves ID tagging the puppies and then tooltipping them at the bottom:

```
$('document').ready(function () { 
    $("#text_title").tooltip({placement: 'bottom', title:"HELLO TITLE!"});
    $("#label_one").tooltip({placement: 'bottom', title:"HELLO ONE!"});
    $("#label_two").tooltip({placement: 'bottom', title:"HELLO TWO!"});
});
```

Example also shows how to add tooltips to the title!