# How to fix formatting of axis labels in Highcharts when surrounding the contents with div?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Here is what the chart currently looks like:[image]

I want to display a tooltip when somebody hovers over one of the X-axis labels. So for that I formatted them the following way (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27613591/6264628)):

```
labels: { useHTML: true, formatter: function() { return '<div id="label_'+this.value.replace(/ /g,'') +'">'+this.value+'</div>'; } }
```

However, after running it, it starts to look like this:[image]

How can I keep the formatting that Highcharts applies while still adding my personal id to each label?

Comment: Hi @droft1312, Could you reproduce the problem in jsfiddle? Here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/prbc049n/ everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the fact that you are using `div` is throwing some highcharts styling off. You could try using `span`.

Or maybe your id is adding some CSS which isn't playing well with highcharts CSS. To check this you could try temporarily commenting out the CSS associated with your id to see if it works that way.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely throwing off some highcharts styling. I have tried using span but that didn't help either. FYI: my id isn't adding any CSS.